# Global optimal sequence alignment algorithms

Tags: algorithms, computational-biology

As far as global optimal sequence alignment goes, is the Needleman-Wunsch and Hirschberg's algorithm still state of the art? Or have there been any improvements to these algorithms since they were published, or any newer algorithms?

Comment: I have no familiarity with these algorithms, or even the general problem, so could you provide links?

Comment: @rcollyer: I'm guessing [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment), but it would have been nice if the OP was a bit more forthcoming...

Comment: @rcollyer Yes that is what I meant. Sorry I didn't provide the background

Comment: @J.M. The author was referring the the following two algorithms: [**The Needleman–Wunsch Algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) and [**Hirschberg's Algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirschberg%27s_algorithm)

Answer (score 6):

According to Wing-Kin Sung's excellent "Algorithms in Bioinformatics" (2010, [pp 30-39](http://books.google.com/books?id=4j_GfM0tyPUC&pg=PA30)), the fastest algorithm was discovered in 1980 by Masek and Paterson and can solve the global alignment problem in $O(nm /\log(n))$ time, which is barely better than the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm:

> W.J Masek and M.S. Paterson. 1980. ["A faster algorithm computing string edit distances."](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000%2880%2990002-1) *Journal of Computer and System Sciences* 20(1):18-31.

Sung's book has a short but well-written section on global alignment.

Comment: Thanks very much for the book link. It looks great! I'll definitely be reading that soon